# Blank Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a function that populates a datagridview using the code given below. It basically displays a list of patients scheduled for a given timeslot and date for up to 7 days (Sun-Sat).

The datagridview is displaying fine on my machine on both release and debug versions. I also tried publishing the application and installing it in the same machine and had no problems at all.

Unfortunately, when the same application is published and installed on a different machine, the datagridview doesn't show any data. The same application also displays other datagridviews for a list of patients and other details and they are all displaying just fine.

I've read a LOT of threads here and have been fiddling with the code but so far, I haven't found any solutions. Is there a problem with the code or is there a problem with any settings of some kind that I am not aware of?

Any help or input will be deeply appreciated.

Edit: I've updated the code to provide more details (just in case)

```
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

//weeArray simply contains 7 dates, (Sun-Sat)
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < weekArray.Length; ctr++)
{
    c.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, c);
    command.CommandText = @"Reealy long sql that I'm sure isn't causing the issue";

    command.Parameters.Add("@scheduleDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = weekArray[ctr];
    command.Parameters.Add("@scheduleStaff_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox2.SelectedValue;

    command.Prepare();
    command.ExecuteReader();

    SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    c.Close();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    a.Fill(dt);

    if (ctr == 0)
    {
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
        if (weekArray[ctr].Equals(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")))
            dataGridView2.Columns["patient"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);
        else
            dataGridView2.Columns["patient"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(230, 255, 255);
    }
    else if (ctr == 1)
    {
        dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;
        if (weekArray[ctr].Equals(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")))
            dataGridView3.Columns["patient"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);
        else
            dataGridView3.Columns["patient"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
    else if (ctr == 2)
    {
        dataGridView4.DataSource = dt;
        if (weekArray[ctr].Equals(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")))
            dataGridView4.Columns["patient"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);
        else
            dataGridView4.Columns["patient"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
    else if (ctr == 3)
    {
        dataGridView5.DataSource = dt;
        if (weekArray[ctr].Equals(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")))
            dataGridView5.Columns["patient"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);
        else
            dataGridView5.Columns["patient"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
    else if (ctr == 4)
    {
        dataGridView6.DataSource = dt;
        if (weekArray[ctr].Equals(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")))
            dataGridView6.Columns["patient"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);
        else
            dataGridView6.Columns["patient"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
    else if (ctr == 5)
    {
        dataGridView7.DataSource = dt;
        if (weekArray[ctr].Equals(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")))
            dataGridView7.Columns["patient"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);
        else
            dataGridView7.Columns["patient"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
    else if (ctr == 6)
    {
        dataGridView8.DataSource = dt;
        if (weekArray[ctr].Equals(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")))
            dataGridView8.Columns["patient"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);
        else
            dataGridView8.Columns["patient"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried with debuging code? dt is fill or not?

Comment: Data table is filled, everything is working perfectly on my machine. The only problem is when I try to run it in a different machine. I'm also quite sure that the issue is not with the database location since it populates all the other datagridviews and loads all needed comboboxes with no problems

Comment: So, in which condition there is a problem? if other are working

Comment: The problem isn't with the conditions (as far as I know), the problem is when deploying the application in a different machine.
Basically:
[my PC -> no problem, all datagridviews display all data]   
[other PC -> these datagridviews are blank, all other datagridviews are displaying data]

Comment: @Squishablez, the code you put is not enough to pin point the issue. Even then I suspect that regional setting on your machine and another machine may be different which is causing date comparison failure resulting in unexpected application flow and finally the datagridview showing nothing.

Comment: You will need to either debug on the other machine or write out logs that show you the states, e.g. DataTable row count etc.. We can't help with either.

Comment: You've all already helped a lot and I really appreciate it. It was very important for me to know that #1 there wasn't anything causing a red flag with how I populated my datagrid and #2 This isn't a common problem encountered when deploying a published application on another machine.
I will see what is causing the issue, remove it from the loop (use different variables for data tables and data adapters) and will be posting the answer here if I manage to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the blank datagridview is caused by the fact that I am using a prepared statement. There are no problems with the statement itself, it just so happens that that section of code doesn't work well with a prepared statement.

Based from what I've read so far, it's usually caused by different/older versions of SQL express and/or .NET framework (sometimes both).

Since that section of code doesn't really require the use of a prepared statement, I've modified it to a simple sqlcommand instead since there will be no user input other than button clicks and the issue was resolved.

The solution was only applicable in this case since there is no user text input involved and an install/upgrade of the SQL/.NET framework isn't a viable option because the target machine is rather old and lacks disk space (aside from other reasons including but not limited to outdated hardware and software.)

(Thanks for all your input, they were a huge help in tracing the problem much more faster.)